# html agility pack getting same output twice c#

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

```html
<div class="header">
  <span id="content">test1</span>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <span id="content">test2</span>
</div>
```

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url)
var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='header']")
foreach(var v in value)
{
var name = v.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='content']")
Console.Writeline(name.OuterHtml);
}
```

the code above gives me as output twice `<span id="content">test1</span>`instead of `<span id="content">test2</span>` as second output. So it gets the correct number of nodes but not the correct output.

Comment: Make sure elements are not repeated in the Document. Try debugging with a break point and get back here with your findings.

Comment: same id for 2 different span?Huaah!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using // and / in XPath will query the root node even you are using the current node.

Please see my fix in your code.

```
var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='header']");
foreach (var v in value)
{
    var name = v.SelectSingleNode("span[@id='content']");
    Console.WriteLine(name.OuterHtml);
}
```

See this fiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/nih2lw

A side note, id attribute should always be unique in the document. Use class instead.